# Page lags when scrolling with multiple images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a form for uploading photos. If a number of rows of images go off screen, the page starts to overload the CPU and lag when scrolling.

Each image is loaded into the application memory via `<input type="file/>` and converted to an image via `URL.createObjectUrl()`.

```js
const newImages = Array.from(event.target.files as FileList).map((file) => URL.createObjectURL(file));
setImages([...images, ...newImages]);

...

images.map((image, index) => (
    <div className="form__photo-container">
        <img src={image} className="form__photo" />
    </div>
))
```

Then I tried 100 images that didn't convert the file to a URL, but just used a link to an existing image on the server. In this case nothing lagged, even if almost all images went off screen.

```js
images.map((image, index) => (
    <div className="form__photo-container">
        <img src={"/img/test.jpg"} className="form__photo" />
    </div>
))
```

My guess is that the lags are due to virtual rendering. The browser engine, when scrolling, starts converting the not yet converted file to a URL over and over again while the user scrolls the page, which causes CPU overload.

So, as I understand it, I need to:

**1) either load each image into the server and create a link to that image instead of loading it into JavaScript memory;**

or

**2) disable image virtualization specifically on this form.**

What else do I need to do or how do I implement the two options above?

Comment: Have you already checked to ensure that your code isn't excessively re-rendering?

Comment: @MichaelM
The ReactDevTools extension says nothing is being re-rendered while scrolling

Answer (score 0):

If u want to stick with the in-memory approach ba disable virtualization for your form, try using a technique like windowing or pagination. so basically you only render a subset of images at a time and as the user scrolls you load/render the next batch of images

some of the top libraries you can use : '[react-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window)' or '[react-virtualized](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized)'.
:)